# changing image on hover but without changing the image position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change a image on hover and it should be pretty straight forward but for some reason it is not changing the image also I noticed there is a kind of jerking.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#first_default_circle').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.default').hide();
        $('#first_default_circle_hover.default_hover').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('#first_default_circle_hover.default_hover').hide();
        $(this).find('.default').show();
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.default {
     height: 86px;
     left: 280px;
     top: 50px;
     width: 86px;
 }
 img {
     position: absolute;
     background:#000;
 }
 .default_hover {
     display: none;
     height: 119px;
     left: 261px;
     top: 40px;
     width: 119px;
 }
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Z6rNF/

Please any kind of help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/Z6rNF/2/)

**JS**

```
$("#circle").hover(

function () {
    $('.default').hide();
    $('.default_hover').show();
},

function () {
    $('.default_hover').hide();
    $('.default').show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle">
    <img src="http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance.png" class="default">
    <img src="http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance_ho.png" class="default_hover">
</div>
```

**Or if you prefer with some fade effect:**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/Z6rNF/4/)**

Comment: Thank you so much.You are a star...is it possible to add animate() with speed and opacity please.

Comment: Just see the last link of my answer just use fadeOut and fadeIn, for example $('.default').fadeOut(250); $('.default_hover').fadeIn(500);

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#first_default_circle').mouseenter(function () {

     $('.default').attr('src','http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance_ho.png')
 }).mouseleave(function () {

     $('.default').attr('src','http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance.png')
 });
```

I highly recommend using mouseenter, mouseout function since they trigger only when you enter and leave an element.

Comment: You will also need to populate newimgurl. As such:
newimgurl = "images/yourfile.png";

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#first_default_circle').mouseenter(function(){
$('#first_default_circle').find('img').attr("src","http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance_ho.png");
});

$('#first_default_circle').mouseleave(function(){
$('#first_default_circle').find('img').attr("src","http://www.demo-pinksquid.co.uk/img/rewarding_icon_private_medical_insurance.png");
});
```

You can use like this instead of your jquery script

Updated link http://jsfiddle.net/Z6rNF/3/

Comment: It's close...Is it possible to make the second image bigger but keeping in the same position?

Comment: Thanks Sathya.If you please see @sbml 's solution then that's the one which I was trying to do.

Comment: If you continuously hover on that image, it will start behavior weirdly.@PrithvirajMitra

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors aren't right:

```
$('#first_default_circle_hover.default_hover')
```

Should be:

```
$('#first_default_circle_hover .default_hover')
```

I also cleaned up your CSS a little.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6rNF/1/

Comment: Thanks.But for some reason the second image is falling down.Can it be same in the position as first image is.